# Capture click event in Angular with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I need to convert the following jquery codes to typescript code.

**Jquery**

```
$(".room").click({
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

**TypeScript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: What stops you from doing so ?

Comment: What @Rayon said + I dont see a question at all.

Comment: Because it is not  recomended to use jQuery inside angular project

Answer (score 3):

On your element that has room class in HTML you can do something like this in your component template:

For example if your element is a button:

```
<button class="room" #btn (click)="buttonClick()">Click Me!</button>
```

And then in your class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

export class AppComponent {
    buttonClick(){
        console.log("Button Clicked!");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your answer is ok to me, but i do not want to wrap it in angular side. i need it globally of full page.

Comment: It is not advisable to have events outside component scope. You have an option to do this on your appComponent, which is the parent most component. That will make it global.